# OnResultExcuting in .NET 6.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

I am migrating ASP.NET application from .NET Framework. 4.8 to .NET 6.0. One of the issues I'm currently experiencing is that I cannot override OnResultExecuting. In the old (.NET Framework) I have the following:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller

protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
   .......
}

protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExectuingContext filterContext)
{
   if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
                return;
            }
}
```

But when I try to implement the same in .NET 6.0, it looks like the Controller does not implement this method.

I was searching for other solutions and I have added custom filter and implemented it like this:

```
[CustomResultFilter]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
```

The problem is that I cannot have this check:

```
   if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
        return;
   }
```

I have them implemented IResultFilter in the BaseController:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller, IResultFilter
```

Then I can add implementation of the OnResultExecuting method, but I cannot call the base functionality of the method `base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);`

Any thoughts or ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. ASP.NET Core 6 is very different from ASP.NET Framework. The entire pipeline is different - there was no DI, no configuration, no logging in ASP.NET MVC but now they're the foundation of everything.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? `OnResultExecuting` is how you implemented it. That doesn't exist any more. [Action, exception and result filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0) do exist. So does [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) that's as easy to add as `app.Use((context,next)=>{ ... })`. You probably don't need to create your own BaseController at all

Comment: Thanks. I think I have what I need for now. I'll try a couple of things and see where it goes.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you're trying to build. There may be a tutorial or doc page just for it. Especially if you want to implement custom authentication. Authentication and authorization filters run before any other filters are called

Comment: Based on what has been build for this project after I have taken it, it looks like all of the controllers in the app are inheriting this BaseController. The controller has a couple of properties, holding different permissions, notifications, errors, etc and after that rest of the controllers are using those properties and methods for validation etc.